# How to generate short fixed length cryptographic hashes?

Tags: hash

I am trying to implement a kind of email verification system with a node.js server with no state.

**The strategy**

1. User sends his email to the server
2. Server generates a 4 digits code based on the email address and sends it to the user via email.
3. User sends back the received code via email + the email address to the server
4. Server re-generates the 4 digits code based on the email and compares it with the code sent by the user.

**My implementation to generate the 4 digits code**

1. Create a HEX digest using HMAC SHA-256 hash function
2. Take the first 3 characters of the digest
3. Convert them to an integer
4. If length < 4, concatenates one or multiples `0` at the end

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const get4DigitsCode = (message) => {
  const hash = crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(SECRET_KEY, 'hex'))
    .update(message)
    .digest('hex')

  const first3HexCharacters = hash.slice(0, 3)

  const int = parseInt(first3HexCharacters, 16)

  let code = int.toString()
  code =
    Array(4 - code.length)
      .fill(0)
      .join("") + code

  return code
}
```

After generating codes for 8293 email addresses, I noticed that I had 4758 duplicates. Is it normal to have this amount of duplicates for a code as this sort? Is my strategy and my implementation secure (ability to guess the code)?

The service is a mobile app, email based (a "mail to self" app). I want a 4 digit code for UX reasons. The user can read the code from the email client notification, easily memorize it and type it in the app (that he never leaves). No tedious copy and paste, not leaving the app, simply read and type. I know that multiple emails would generate the same code, but it doesn't matter as it is just for validating emails. Also I will protect the APIs against brute-force.

Can someone guess the code with this strategy (what are the risks or possible attacks?) and is my current implementation correct?

**UPDATE**

A better implementation thanks to [@duskwuff's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/218060/217726) :

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const get4DigitsCode = (message) => {
    const hash = crypto
        .createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(SECRET, 'hex'))
        .update(message)
        .digest('hex');
    const first4HexCharacters = hash.slice(0, 4);
    const int = parseInt(first4HexCharacters, 16) % 10000;
    let code = int.toString();
    code =
        Array(4 - code.length)
            .fill(0)
            .join('') + code;
    return code;
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98924/discussion-on-question-by-thomas-how-to-generate-short-fixed-length-cryptographi).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The cryptographical hash function with output size `n` has `√n` collision with probability 50% due to the birthday paradox.

You took 3 hexadecimal digits which means you get 12 bits. After 2<sup>6</sup>=64 hash generations, you will see a collision with 50% probability.

Collision in hash functions is inevitable due to the fixed-sized output space but the arbitrary length of input space. [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) tells us that collision is inevitable.

If you want low collision probability you have to use larger output as 128-bit. For 128-bit we expect at least one collision in 2<sup>64</sup> hashes with 50% probability.

We are not accepting that the system is secret, we assume it is known. E-Mails are not secret and any attacker can create his code by using your source code. An attacker or a group of attackers can try to attack your system due to short token. The mitigation is increasing the token size.

For most applications using `read("/dev/urandom", 16)` will be fine or you can use `HMAC($email, $key)` without trimming. Copy and paste shouldn't be a problem for the user.

If you need higher resistance you may use digital signatures; first hash the e-mail then sign.

Comment: Why `2^6` ? 
_any attacker can create his code by using your code._ Of course I will use a secret key for the Hmac.

Comment: Basically, you took 3 of the hex code, so you have 12-bits output which has 2^{12} space take the square root. The secret key residing in code is problematic.

Comment: Note, also a random e-mail can impersonate according to the birthday bound which is too low.

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph. How can I create a code using your code? Why would your email not be secret? Why would OP need a signature scheme?!

Comment: @kelalaka I don't see a Problem, using a secret Key with a hash function should be just as secure as using a digital signature. The key will obviously not reside in the code but will be read from a secure environment (just like a private keyfile would be) - the only real downside is the small search-space, which can not easily be rate-limited, since an attacker could just try on average 2000 random mail-addresses to find one which matches the code "1234"

Comment: @Falco do you think that 1/2000 change is not to worth to attack?

Comment: @kelalaka of course that is much to low. I wanted to make a point that this is a serious problem, but has nothing to do with generating the code with part of a hash.

Comment: Birthday paradox is only half the solution (that would determine why with a 100 you would be more likely to have a duplicate) - here, there is a duplicate with 100% certainty because the secret code is using a space with only 4096 possibilities.

Comment: @kelalaka Oh, I think I misunderstood your answer. You were talking about the email *address* that is not secret, not the email contents! As for "create his code by using your code", do you mean: "create his security token by using your source code"? If 'yes' to both, that changes the answer completely. Still, no need for signatures (`read("/dev/urandom", 16)` will do just fine, or `hmac($email, $key)` which is not a signature but a MAC), but other than that, I think I understand what you meant to say now.

Comment: @kelalaka I understand that 4 digits is small and I will have collisions and low security. But you don't really have answer the initial question : "How to generate short fixed length cryptographic hashes?". Do you have a better alternative to produce a 4 digits signed hash ?

Comment: @Thomas In CS there is hash tables where the collision is resolved by chaining etc. Use longer, user can just copy and paste. This must be solve you issues as long as you have something else in your mind.

Comment: `sqrt(n)` is not how Birthday Paradox probabilities work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: @domen see section [Cast as a collision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem)

Comment: @kelalaka, taking the approximation formula from that section, one expects 50% of collision with 76 12-bit hashes (vs. 64 or `sqrt(2**12)`). I agree that for big `n` it's pretty much the same as `sqrt`. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @domen as n goes to infinity it is a good approximation. I used without the big O notation, in general, it is clear to all. For small n you need numbers.

Comment: @kelalaka I have added some context in the original post : "I want a 4 digit code for UX reasons. The user can read the code from the email client notification, easily memorize it and type it in the app (that he never leaves). No tedious copy and paste, not leaving the app, simply read and type."

Comment: Thomas, I prefer copy and paste. I tend to not remember easily. If you use base64 encdoing the copy and past shouldn't be a problem. Note: changing an answered question is not a good idea for the post. The answers and questions can become unrelated.

Answer (score 11):

There are a couple of pretty serious problems with this approach which will increase the risk of collisions beyond what would ordinarily be expected for a random 4-digit value.

> 2. Take the first 3 characters of the digest
> 3. Convert them to an integer

Three hexadecimal digits gives you a range of 0 – 4095 (`0x000 - 0xfff`). This will give you a lot more collisions than expected for a 4-digit number, because you're only using 40% of the possible values.

Use a larger excerpt of the digest and use a modulus operation (`% 10000`) to force the result to be four decimal digits long. For numerical reasons, using the first 10 hexadecimal digits (40 bits) is pretty close to ideal. (Multiples of 10 bits give you rough powers of 1000, and 40 bits is large but below the maximum safe integer of 2<sup>53</sup>.)

> 4. If length < 4, concatenates one or multiples 0 at the end

This introduces *even more* collisions. Values from 1 - 4, 10 – 40, and 100 – 400 all get mapped onto the same 1000 – 4000 range, and there's some secondary collisions for sets of values like 5, 50, and 500.

If you need to pad with zeroes, do it on the left side, not the right.

Comment: 2^53 is only the valid range for integers if the language is using an IEEE double to hold numbers.  In C/C++ the limit is only 2^32 for `int` (technically 2^16, but essentially *nobody* uses that), you have to use `long long` to be sure of being able to hold 2^40 - but that holds 2^64.  In python of course, there is no limit at all to how big an integer can be.

Comment: Note that the number of collisions pretty much exactly matches a perfect low-collision hash function. With ~4000 possible hashes and ~8000 inputs, the best you could achieve with the perfect hash function is ~4000 collisions. sha256 is quite neat ;-)

Comment: Instead of the modulus operation, would it be simpler to take the first 4 digits of the number ?

Comment: Simpler, but horribly wrong in many of the same ways as your first attempt. Consider that the first four digits of a number between 0 and 65535 will usually be between 1000 and 6553.

Comment: Ok, got it! And what do you think about the use of HMAC? It is a good way to generate a personalized (with secret) hash?